# Derive logic for 2 "check bytes" for a USB fingerprint reader

Tags: crc, checksum

I have been working on reverse engineering and building a Linux driver for a fingerprint reader and have most of it sorted out, but one thing which continues to elude me is that there seems to be 2 bytes in each payload that are some kind of "check bytes." I am not sure if one or both are some kind of CRC, a simple sum or XOR of the bytes in some order, maybe some offset or constant XOR being applied to them, or something? But it seems like any kind of logic I work out for 2 or 3 of the examples does not fit for the others.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what how these could be generated?  More info here if you are super curious to dig in: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/569

The "payloads" seem to have an 8 byte prefix (one when reading from the device's bulk in, and one when sending to the device's bulk out), followed by these 2 "check" bytes (not calling them a "checksum" yet as I am not sure what either of them actually represent), then 3 "0" bytes, and either 1 or 2 bytes of some kind
of type/subtype byte to indicate the type of event or message being sent, finally followed by some kind of "actual" payload for the specific event.

I am still not sure if the prefix is included in the check algorithm or if it only looks at what comes payload which comes after everything else, or if when there is occasionally some type/subtype suffixes that these are or are not included either.

But here are some examples:

BULK IN example payloads (as hex bytes) read from the device during a trace:

```
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 d5 6d 00 00 00 02 90 00
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 d4 6d 00 00 00 02 91 00
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 d5 69 00 00 00 02 90 04
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 ff 6f 00 00 00 02 65 fe
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 ff d0 00 00 00 04 01 0a 64 91
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 fe d0 00 00 00 04 02 0a 64 91
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 d2 61 00 00 00 04 03 0a 90 00
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 cb 61 00 00 00 04 0a 0a 90 00
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 3a d8 00 00 00 0d 39 30 35 30 2e 31 2e 31 2e 38 31 90 00
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 8d 2c 00 00 00 06 02 04 46 39 90 00
53 49 47 45 00 00 00 01 9f a5 00 00 00 22 01 89 c4 7f 37 a5 e6 f9 81 c2 b5 45 66 ec 3b ff 26 04 39 77 cb 35 44 ae e8 1d 29 93 41 c0 b4 3b 90 00
```

BULK OUT example payloads (as hex bytes) sent to the device from the Windows driver during a trace:

```
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 04 54 00 00 00 07 50 07 00 02 00 00 1d
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 1d 1a 00 00 00 07 50 43 00 00 00 00 04
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 00 47 00 00 00 07 50 16 01 00 00 00 20
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 1d 45 00 00 00 07 50 16 02 02 00 00 02
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 21 46 00 00 00 04 50 1a 00 00
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 1f 49 00 00 00 04 50 16 02 01
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 fc 46 00 00 00 07 50 16 05 00 00 00 20
45 47 49 53 00 00 00 01 55 f1 00 00 00 27 50 16 03 00 00 00 20 01 89 c4 7f 37 a5 e6 f9 81 c2 b5 45 66 ec 3b ff 26 04 39 77 cb 35 44 ae e8 1d 29 93 41 c0 b4 3b
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every line the sum of all big-endian words modulo `0xFFFF` equals to 0.
Example (the last line):

```
0x4547 + 0x4953 + 0x0000 + ... + 0x9341 + 0xc0b4 + 0x3b00 = 0x9FFF6
```

To verify the checksum:

- append zero byte if number of bytes is odd;
- calculate 32-bit sum of 16-bit words;
- split the sum into 16 low bits and 16 high bits;
- calculate the 16-bit sum (or `xor`) of the two halves;
- the result must be equal to `0xFFFF`.

Comment: Thanks @ESkri that is incredibly well spotted! I was able to take the observations you made and rough out a basic formula `0xFFFF - (sum_of_32bit_words % 0xFFFF)` that I guess gives essentially the "first possibility" of a reverse mod and the USB device seems to like it!  So I will clean up the code a bit and update... thank you for the help!